# angular2 forms observable / event

Tags: typescript, angular, typescript1.5

Based on David East tutorial (https://gist.github.com/davideast/0b7efc93e0ba9aaa446e) I'm trying to get Angular2 observable working on very tiny forms example.

Basically I would like that each time an input value changes some event is fired and caught by my observer. But for some weird reason my code doesn't work...

lib versions: typescript 1.5.0-beta, Angular-2.0.0-28

Here is the Typescript code:

```
/// <reference path="../../typings/angular2/angular2.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="../../typings/angular2/angular2_addons.d.ts" />
import {Component, View, bootstrap, Form, EventEmitter} from 'angular2/angular2';
import {FormBuilder, Validators, formDirectives, ControlGroup} from 'angular2/forms';
import {Inject} from 'angular2/di';

@Component({
  selector: 'mycmp',
  appInjector: [FormBuilder]
})
@View({
  template: '<form [ng-form-model]="myForm"><input type="text" ng-control="myText">{{myForm.controls.myText.value}}</form>',
  directives: [formDirectives],
})
export class MyCmp {
  myForm:ControlGroup;
  constructor(@Inject(FormBuilder) builder:FormBuilder) {
    this.myForm = builder.group({
        myText: ["someDefaultVal...", Validators.required]
    });

    this.myForm.controls.myText.valueChanges.subscribe(function (value) {
        console.log("changed value=" + value);
    }.bind(this));
  }
}

bootstrap(MyCmp);
```

Unfortunately I'm getting `TypeError: this.myForm.controls.myText.valueChanges.subscribe is not a function`

Comment: did you missing  import ReactiveFormsModule or  rxjs/add/*?

Answer (score 3):

This [blog post](http://blog.jhades.org/introduction-to-angular-2-forms-template-driven-vs-model-driven/) goes into explaining difference between the *old* two-way binding approach and the *new* reactive approach in Angular 2 forms. For the latter, it works with some `form.valueChanges` stream as in the following:

```
this.form.valueChanges
  .map((value) => {
      value.firstName = value.firstName.toUpperCase();
      return value;
  })
  .filter((value) => this.form.valid)
  .subscribe((value) => {
     console.log("Model Driven Form valid value: vm = " + JSON.stringify(value));
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

I could not find any subscriber function, so I used the observer:

```
this.myForm.valueChanges.observer({next: (value) => this.address = value});
```

In this case "this.address" is an object representing myForm data.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to fire some function every time the value of your input changes, then you can do something like this:

```
<input type="text" ng-control="myText" #mytext (keyup)="firechange($event,mytext)">
```

and in your component

```
firechange($event, field){
    console.log(field.value);
}
```

And you don't need to use `@Inject` if you have already `appInject` (which is, btw, gone in alpha29 (https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#breaking-changes). It can be just:

```
constructor(builder: FormBuilder) {...}
```